# Optimizing PIL/numpy routine

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, python-imaging-library

I am working with a PIL image that's been cleaned to be black and white. The images are about 200x200 pixels.

The process works like this where the idea is that I want just the indexes of the black pixels in the image

```
self.image = Image.open(path)
npArray = numpy.array(Image.open(self.image.getdata(),
                                   numpy.uint8).reshape(self.image.size[1], self.image.size[0], 4)

black = [(i, j) for i in range(1,dim-1) for j in range(1,dim-1) if  npArray[i][j][0] == 0]

return numpy.asarray(black)
```

For the most part it works but is a bottleneck to performance. Any ideas how I might speed it up?

Comment: Are you using Python3?

Comment: `xind, yind = np.where(img[...,0] == 0)` may do what you want (I don't have a b&w image handy to verify).

Comment: Or, if you want the coordinates as pairs, use `np.argwhere(img[..., 0] == 0)`.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Nice, I didn't know about `argwhere` yet.

Comment: Thanks argwhere cut the time down from 16 seconds to 5 on my machine.